# wordpress blog with jsp

Tags: wordpress, spring, jsp, web

I have to set up wordpress blog. my problem is, i am using spring/jsp for website development, so the url and port number are different for wordpress(php) blog and the website. I have to integrate the blog in the site which currently i am doing using iframe.
But with iframe, the problem is i can't calculate the height of iframe as it is on a different url, so i have to make footer fixed and only the blog part will be scrollable.

Is there any way or any alternative to integrate wordpress blog?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has an rpc-api. You can use it to query for the articles, but then you have to render them by your own.